# dynamic value class - schema not known until runtime

Tags: geode

All the examples for storing multi-field data require specifying a value class.  However, I do not know the fields or their types until run-time.  I would like to be able to create a region with a dynamic set of field values.  For example,

`put --key=101 --value=('firstname':'James','lastname':'Gosling') 
--region=/region1 --value-class=data.Person`

However, the `data.Person` class does not exist.

Furthermore, I would like to be able to query on the `firstname` field (or any other field of the value).

How can I do this with Geode?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a domain class to store data in Geode. You can store `json` [natively in Geode](http://geode.docs.pivotal.io/docs/developing/data_serialization/jsonformatter_pdxinstances.html). OQL queries make no distinction between PDX serialized objects and json values. In fact, when you store a `json` value in Geode, beneath the covers it is converted into a `PDXInstance`. You can read more about PDX Serialization in the [documentation](http://geode.docs.pivotal.io/docs/developing/data_serialization/gemfire_pdx_serialization.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PdxInstance](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/developing/data_serialization/using_PdxInstanceFactory.html).

Example using Java:

```
region.put(101, cache.createPdxInstanceFactory("data.Person").writeString("firstname","James")
                .writeString("lastname","lastname").create());
```